# React: props is not defined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have the following code in a product, js, I'm trying to return a single item on API call using the id param. When I run I get props not defined. I don't know how to solve this

```
import React, {useEffect }from 'react';

import { detailsProduct } from '../actions/productActions';
  
function Productscreen(props) {

const productDetails = useSelector(state => state.productDetails);

const {product , loading, error } = productDetails;

const dispatch = useDispatch();
useEffect(() => {

  dispatch(detailsProduct(props.match.params.id));

  return () => {
    //
  }
}, [])
```

[image]

Comment: where are you calling `ProductScreen` ?

Comment: on the main App.js

Comment: Please show how you are using `Productscreen`. Note that you are not supposed to call React function components yourself - and that would be the only way to trigger this error. And this makes little sense as a React component because the function doesn't return anything.

Comment: sorry for the mixup the funtion should return a div with a product with the given id passed in props

Comment: @kipruto The error `Uncaught ReferenceError: props is not defined` comes from trying to use a variable that you did not define anywhere. In the code you posted I don't see anywhere where you are using `props` that are not defined. Your effect also has a [stale closure](https://dmitripavlutin.com/react-hooks-stale-closures/) you either are not using a linter (dangerous if you don't understand hooks) or did not see the warning the linter gave you.

Answer (score 1):

The way you pass the component to your route matters. To have access to match, you would have needed the render prop to destructure the match.

```
<Route path='/whatever/:id' render={({match}) => <Productscreen match={match} />} />
```

You can also use the new react router hooks [useParams](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/useparams), I prefer them, mostly because of Typescript.

```
import React, {useEffect } from 'react';
import { detailsProduct } from '../actions/productActions';
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";

function Productscreen() {
    const productDetails = useSelector(state => state.productDetails);
    const {product , loading, error } = productDetails;

    let { id } = useParams()

    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    useEffect(() => {
         dispatch(detailsProduct(id));`

          return () => {
                //
          }
    }, [])
}
```

in that case, your route should be:

```
<Route path="/whateverpath/:id">
  <Productscreen/>
</Route>
```

Comment: I have refactored the code as you've said and it still throws the error props not defined

Comment: if you are using the render method, destructure in the function Productscreen({match})  and try logging it

Comment: I'm using return